# Running NodeJS App with Socket IO on Shared CPanel server Unexpected token

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, cpanel

I created a very simple socket IO app which receives a message and posts it back in a socket group.

The app is running successfully on my Windows machine with Node.js v12.14.0. But I want to get rid of my port forwarding so asked my hoster if it was possible to run the Node.js app on Cpanel. They were not a fan, but opened it up.

I had to install the dependencies manually but finally got no more dependency error while starting the app, but ended up with the error below. After doing some google-ing it probably has to do with the Node.js version on the server which is v6.16.0 . The hoster says they can't get this updated as it comes with cpanel. Now I was hoping there is a way to get my app.js running on this version.

Error:

```
enter code here[username@server app]$ node /home/username/domains/website.nl/app/app.js
/home/username/domains/website.nl/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:347
  ...options
  ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/username/domains/website.nl/app/node_modules/ws/index.js:3:19)
[username@server app]$ node -v
v6.16.0
```

The app:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');


var prvKey = fs.readFileSync('/home/username/ssl/keys/1.key').toString();
var prvCert = fs.readFileSync('/home/username/ssl/certs/1.crt').toString();
var server = https.createServer({key:prvKey,cert:prvCert});

var serverPort = 3000;

// var server = https.createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(serverPort, function() {
  console.log('server up and running at %s port', serverPort);
});



io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    console.log("user connected: " + socket.id + " - " + socket.request.connection.remoteAddress);
    var activequizid = null;
    socket.on('jsondata', function(data){
        if(data.join.join == "true"){
            console.log(socket.id + " join group " + data.join.quizid)
            socket.join(data.join.quizid)
        }
    })
    socket.on('jsondataupdate', function(data){
        console.log(data.update)
        if(data.update.status){
            socket.to(data.update.quizid).emit('update', data.update);
        }
    })

    socket.on("disconnect", function(socketd) {
        console.log(socketd)
        console.log(this.id)
    });

    socket.on('connection', function () {
        console.log('connection!')
    })

    socket.on('reconnecting', function () {
        console.log('reconnecting!')
    })

    socket.on('reconnect', function () {
        console.log('reconnect!')
    })

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('disconnect!')
    })

});

console.log("sever online")
```

websocket.js (partly function with error (look for "...options")) :

```
  send(data, options, cb) {
      if (this.readyState === WebSocket.CONNECTING) {
        throw new Error('WebSocket is not open: readyState 0 (CONNECTING)');
      }

      if (typeof options === 'function') {
        cb = options;
        options = {};
      }

      if (typeof data === 'number') data = data.toString();

      if (this.readyState !== WebSocket.OPEN) {
        sendAfterClose(this, data, cb);
        return;
      }

      const opts = {
        binary: typeof data !== 'string',
        mask: !this._isServer,
        compress: true,
        fin: true,
        ...options
      };

      if (!this._extensions[PerMessageDeflate.extensionName]) {
        opts.compress = false;
      }

      this._sender.send(data || EMPTY_BUFFER, opts, cb);
    }
```